# Automated tests in phantomJS: how to access console logs

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS for automated testing. I want to know if there is a way by which an automated test can access console logs. I don't know if phantomJS publishes console logs since it's a headless browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean ?

Of course, you can write to console or use arguments in you script.

Here is a very basic example

```
var args = require('system').args;
if (args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Try to pass some arguments when invoking this script!');
}
else {
    args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
        console.log(i + ': ' + arg);
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**
You seems to be confused by the two contexts :  the PhantomJS program itself and the webpage opened in your headless browser. It's not the same at all.

Just add an handler to [webpage.onConsoleMessage](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html)

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
  console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
}
```

Here we are writing somehting in the program console coming from the webpage console.

Comment: But how can you read what gets written to console? This would help when trying to figure out why a test has failed, or why it works in Chrome but not in PhantomJS.